# Why can't I change the name of the file in php passed through jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Good day to all users!
Faced the problem that it is impossible to change the name of the file in php passed from jquery:
With this code in js, I am passing the file to the handler in php:

```
var url = '/temp.php';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files[]', file);  
xhr.open('POST', url, true); 

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
});
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
}
else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
}
});

xhr.send(formData);
```

Php-handler temp.php:

```
$fileNames = $_POST['n0'];
$fname = explode(",", $fileNames);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fname); $i++) {
    $uploaddir = "/mnt/ElmaFiles/$fname[$i]";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploaddir);
}
```

The `$fname` array stores the names of the files passed by transliteration.
The problem is that in the `move_uploaded_file()` method in the second argument where it specifies the save path and file name, I cannot save the file with a new name, it simply is not saved.
I tried to print `echo($_FILES['files']['name']['$i'])` this line is empty. Can you please tell me how can I change the name of the saved file transferred through jquery? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: $uploaddir = "/mnt/ElmaFiles/" . "new_name" . rand();

Comment: Rewrite this line.

Comment: @JohnDoe wow, it works. Truth now I do not understand what the problem is. My array `fname` has the names of the files that I am passing. And they are correct. I tried to output through `echo(fname[$i])` everything is correct.

Comment: Actually you was not passing the name of files. rand() generate random values for your file names.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: @JohnDoe But how so, I do not understand. I'm really sure my array is correct. However, the files are not saved with names from the array. Thank you very much for prompting me. It is very useful!

Comment: You are just passing the temporary path not the filename itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-Write the below line

```
$uploaddir = "/mnt/ElmaFiles/$fname[$i]";
```

with

```
$uploaddir = "/mnt/ElmaFiles/" . "new_name" . rand();
```

It will save your file with random value from now on. You can also add custom naming here.